# Ошибка при выполнении запроса (из 1C)

Tags: java, api, 1с

У нас из обработки 1С раньше все работала, пару недель назад перестала отображать точки на карте.

Вопрос: Что нужно отдавать на ход данной функции

```
router = new ymaps.route(arr,  { mapStateAutoApply: true,  
preset:'islands#nightIcon' });
```

из http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.42

Answer (score 0):

См: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/route-docpage/ ты бы лучше код 1С показал; 
Конструктор

*router.Route(json[, options])*

Параметры:
Параметр    Значение по умолчанию   Описание
json *  —   Тип: Object

Описание маршрута в формате json.

options —   Тип: Object

Опции маршрута.

Comment: а адреса такого вида функция понимает?:

Comment: 143402, Московская обл, Красногорский р-н, Красногорск г, Железнодорожный проезд, дом № 7